# Celery vs. AWS Lambda funcions for lot of long running tasks

Tags: aws-lambda, parallel-processing, celery, django-celery

Is better to use for a lot of long running tasks Celery or AWS Lambda function or something different? I have a function that makes http requests. each function need to run separately and parallel, because there is a time when i can make requests.

I have one celery shared_task which run loop for every url (there is another loop for posting data), but it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

If you have long-running tasks on AWS, ECS Tasks might be the most cost-effective solution. [Unlike long-running services](https://exanubes.com/blog/ecs-tasks-vs-services), ECS tasks are one-off container executions.

You can run ECS Tasks on Fargate or an EC2 Cluster; go with EC2 if you have continuous load and are comfortable managning VMs, or go with Fargate if you have spiky loads and/or don’t want to manage the underlying cluster.